# How to detect when there is 2 User/Account in 1 computer and detect the one that is currently using

Tags: c#, file, directory

This works very fine when the PC only has 1 user/account, but when I tried it on my laptop it just says invalid (directory)

```
private static void CreateWatcher()
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

            watcher.Filter = "*.txt*";

            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_FileCreatedAsync);

            String UserName = Environment.UserName;
            watcher.Path = $@"C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Secret\secret";

            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        private static async void Watcher_FileCreatedAsync(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Txt has been created");
        }


        private async void Loginc_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateWatcher();
        }
```

Comment: Does the directory `C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Secret\secret` exist on your laptop?

Comment: Yes, but there is 2 user so it doesn't know what to choose.

Comment: If the directory doesn't exist, you will have to create it first. By the way, you can use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` to get the first part of the path. ("C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local")

Comment: Exactly what @Herohtar said except can -> must... There is no other way to know where special folders are located...

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments you can (should) use:

```c#
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

And then I also recommend using `Path.Combine`, like this:

```c#
var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
watcher.Path = Path.Combine(basePath, "Secret", "secret");
```

Instead of manually building the path.